# Convolutions on 4 images separately

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset with each data point having 4 images (different pixel sizes for each) that are correlated to each other. I want to do convolutions on them separately, and then combine the information for the 4 images and feed it to 1 dense network. How can I do this in keras functional API?

I also have 10 other features that are not images. I plan to feed it directly to the dense end of the network.

So what I want is:

```
4 independent conv layers
flatten 
concatenate 
Dense layers
1 Output
```

How can I provide the input to keras in such a way?

Comment: Train 5 different models, 4 for images and concatenate the outputs of all these 4 layers and 10 other features and feed it into the 5th model?

Comment: Yes this would work, if there is no way to split up the data within the model then I'll be forced to create separate models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the description you provided, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
input_im1 = Input(...)
input_im2 = Input(...)
input_im3 = Input(...)
input_im4 = Input(...)

conv_im1 = Conv2D(...)(input_im1)
conv_im2 = Conv2D(...)(input_im2)
conv_im3 = Conv2D(...)(input_im3)
conv_im4 = Conv2D(...)(input_im4)

concat_conv = concatenate([conv_im1,conv_im2,conv_im3,conv_im4])
flatten_conv = Flatten()(concat_conv)
input_feat = Input(...)
concat_conv_feat = concatenate([flatten_conv, input_feat])

output = Dense(...)(concat_conv_feat)

model = Model([input_im1,input_im2,input_im3,input_im4,input_feat], output)
```

Though, I am not aware of the sizes of the input images and the parameters for each of the convolution layers. So you may need to modify the code above to adjust it to your exact requirements.

Comment: I had a doubt as to why you added the `input_feat` layer?

Comment: @AbhishekSehgal Because the OP has asked for it: "I also have 10 other features that are not images. I plan to feed it directly to the dense end of the network."

Comment: Thanks, this answer is works. I thought there might be a way to reshape and break the input images within the neural network. It would be useful to me because the input images are also created by another neural net (like a GAN) but both can be separated into 5 parts. Thanks!